# How to find the nearest 8 points for each point in a point set with more than 1M points with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have hundreds of gz files, each includes coordinates for around 0.5M~1M rectangle boxes, each box has a unique index called `localIdx`, the coordinates for each box are `llx, lly, urx, ury,` I can get the x/y for each box by `x=(llx+urx)/2, y=(lly+ury)/2` so that I convert the boxes to points, now I want to find the nearest 8 points(boxes) for each point(box) which returns their localIdx.

Here is what I do:

```
1. read in the gz files with python pandas
2. set the column 'localIdx' for each point as index
3. get the height and width for each box by h=ury-lly, w=urx-llx
4. for each point, filter in points that x is in range current_point_x +/- 20*w, y is in range current_point_y +/- 20*h
5. convert to the filtered_in_points x/y and current_point x/y into two 2D numpy array
6. get the Euclidean Distance by scipy.spatial.distance.cdist
7. merge the result of step6 to the filtered_in pandas to map the localIdx
8. selected 8 nearest localIdx and combine them as a string
9. give the localIdx string for each point
```

Here is the core function from my code:

```
    def seek_norm_list(line, target_df=None, rmax=None, nmax=None, keycol=None):
    if line.padType == 'DUT':
        res_id = []
        key_value = line[keycol]
        current_pad = np.array([[line.xbbox, line.ybbox]])
        h, w = line['h'], line['w']
        h1, h2 = line.ybbox - h*20, line.ybbox + h*20
        w1, w2 = line.xbbox - w*20, line.xbbox + w*20
        target_mask = (target_df['xbbox'] > h1) & (target_df['xbbox'] < h2) & (target_df['ybbox'] > w1) & (target_df['ybbox'] < w2)
        target_df = target_df[target_mask]
        nbh_blks = line.nbh_blk.split(":")
        a = np.array(list(zip(target_df.xbbox, target_df.ybbox)))
        if len(a) > 0:
            d = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(a, current_pad)
            target_df['dist'] = d
            key_target = target_df[target_df[keycol] == key_value]
            key_target.sort_values(by='dist', inplace=True)
            res_target = key_target[key_target.dist < rmax]
            keep_id = list(res_target['localIdx'])
            if line['localIdx'] in keep_id:
                keep_id.remove(line['localIdx'])
            if len(keep_id) > int(nmax):
                keep_id = keep_id[:int(nmax)]
            for bk in nbh_blks:
                for id in keep_id:
                    if bk in id:
                        res_id.append(id)
            line['normList'] = ":".join(res_id)
            line['refCount'] = len(res_id)
            if len(res_id) > 0:
                min, max = keep_id[0], keep_id[-1]
                line['minDist'] = res_target.loc[min, 'dist']
                line['maxDist'] = res_target.loc[max, 'dist']
            else:
                line['minDist'] = ''
                line['maxDist'] = ''
        else:
            line['normList'], line['refCount'] = '', ''
            line['minDist'], line['maxDist'] = '', ''
        return line
    else:
        line['normList'], line['refCount'] = '', ''
        line['minDist'], line['maxDist'] = '', ''
        return line
```

this is very, very slow for each gz file, and in my case, there are ~600 files. total line of all the files are >120M rows.
and I used multiprocessing in my machine which is 16-core.

I want to make it get the result within 3hrs, is this possible with python?

Answer (score 0):

K nearest neighbours. Could use sklearn.

Comment: Thanks! I read the API of sklearn NearestNeighbors, but I found in my case I still need to calculate >100M times as I want to find the nearest points for each point.looks like it's still slow